# PHP nl2br() basic function

Tags: php, line-breaks

Can somebody please help me with this mail script.

I'm simply trying to send an html email and part of the message is from a user textarea, which puts in \r\n.

I seem to be unable to use nl2br or any other similar function. The code below isn't what I'm using but still produces the error.

The code:

```
$to  = 'example@gmail.com';

$subject = 'Test Subject';

$message_var_1 = 'test1 \r\n test2 \r\n test3';
$message = nl2br("
    <div>
    <div>$message_var_1</div>
    </div>
");

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion() . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: You need to be way more attentive. At least to determine that your problem has nothing to do with e-mailing.

Comment: @Guillaume Lebourgeois, I think he uses the expression "produces the error" as synonym for "doesn't work". There's probably no error message at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$message_var_1 = 'test1 \r\n test2 \r\n test3';
```

PHP parses `\r` and `\n` only within `"`, not within `'`. So `nl2br` won't apply here.

```
$message_var_1 = "test1 \r\n test2 \r\n test3";
$message = '<div>
     <div>'.nl2br($message_var_1).'</div>
</div>';
```

This ought to work.

Comment: Solves the problem. Thanks! But why does php have to 'parse' \r\n in order to replace it with <br/>? That seems unnecessary... or do they do it specifically so that you can put single quotes and exclude it from applying nl2br?

Comment: @Derek `nl2br` replaces newlines with a <br> tag and a newline. It is looking for newlines, not a literal `\r\n` (which is a windows-style newline between `"` quotes) - that's why they need to be parsed for `nl2br` to work.

Answer (score 1):

This string contains embedded newlines so you'll end up with a few unwanted `<br/>`s.

```
$message = nl2br("
    <div>
    <div>$message_var_1</div>
    </div>
");
```

You can:

```
$message = "<div>" . nl2br($message_var_1) . "</div>";
```

Or, its much easier to use a [`<pre>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.4) tag:

```
$message = "<pre>$message_var_1</pre>";
```

Comment: The `pre` tag though is normally assigned a `font-family: monospace` which in most cases is not what you want.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative is to use HEREDOC.

```
$message = <<<OUTPUT
 <div> some text 
   <div> some more text </div>
 </div>
OUTPUT;
$message = nl2br($message);
```

Manual link for heredoc [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)