# newline issues in PHP email

Tags: php

I am trying to make messages show newline characters as the customer types it, but I am getting `/r/n` between each line. I also want the `$body .= $_SESSION['username'];` to appear on a separate line.

I have tried to use this example: [PHP nl2br() basic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396147/php-nl2br-basic-function-help) to solve, but have not been successful.

PHP:

```
$body .= $_SESSION['username'];
$body .= $message;
$to = $email;
$subject = "copy of your notification"; 
$headers = "From: noti@r.co.uk\r\n";  
$headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc:noti@r.co.uk' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

HTML form:

```
<form action="notification.php" method="Post" class="rl">
    <div>
        <label for="message" class="fixedwidth">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="40" id="message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="buttonarea">
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="notify" value="Notify"></p>
        </div>
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `PHP_EOL` constant:

```
$body .= $_SESSION['username'].PHP_EOL;
```