# line break issues with sending phpmail

Tags: php

please i am trying to make the message show on newline as the customer types it, but i am getting `/r/n` between each line and also trying to make the `$body .= $_SESSION['username'];` appear on a separate line i have tried to use [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396147/php-nl2br-basic-function-help) to solve but has not been successful the code is below

```
   <?php require_once("include/session.php");?>
<?php require_once("include/dataconnect.php");?>
<?php require_once("include/functions.php");?>
<?php include("include/mheader.php");?>

<?php
$submit = $_POST['Notify'];
$message = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['message'])));
//echo "$message";
//die();
if('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) 
{
if (isset($message)) 
{
//Get Email Address
    $emails = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM reusers WHERE username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'")or die(mysql_error());
    //$emails = mysql_query("SELECT reusers.email FROM reusers INNER JOIN repplac ON reusers.username = repplac.Uname AND reusers.username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")or die(mysql_error());
    $results = (mysql_fetch_assoc($emails)) or die(mysql_error());
    $email= $results['email'];
    //echo "$email";
    //die();
     if(mysql_num_rows($emails) == 0){
         exit("No email addresses found for user '{$_SESSION['username']}'");
    }
    $email = mysql_result($emails, 0);
    //echo "$email";
    //die();
$body = $_SESSION['username']. "<br>"
         . nl2br($_POST['message']);
    $to = $email;
   $subject = "copy of your notification"; 
$headers = "From: noti@r.co.uk\r\n";  
$headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc:noti@r.co.uk' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
    }
    }  
?>
<p>
<form action='notification.php' method='Post' class='rl'>
    <div>
    <label for='message' class='fixedwidth'>Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" rows ="7" cols="40" id="message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class='buttonarea'>
            <p>
            <input type='submit' name='notify' value='Notify'>
            </p>
            </div>
            </form>
            </p>

<?php include("include/footer.php");?>
```

Comment: You need to sort out the incorrect nesting of your HTML. Some browsers will foul the display for your mistakes here

Comment: you should also replace all the `\r\n` in your header with `PHP_EOL` to make it compatible cross platform

Comment: @LawrenceCherone not really; it _should_ be `\r\n` in MIME headers and for the content it doesn't really matter, in fact Outlook on Windows is happier with `\n` rather than `\r\n` (it strips duplicate line endings and counts both `\r` and `\n`) - besides PHP_EOL will set the line endings as they are on the web-server rather than what you want them to be at the point of receipt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's generally safer to send HTML emails in a more archaic form of HTML I'm going to allow the HTML email content to be HTML 4; so it doesn't need to be XML well formed and `nl2br()` is acceptable.

You're specifying that the content of your email is HTML so normal line endings, `\r`, `\n` and `\r\n` are pretty much irrelevant.

Try something like:

```
$body = $_SESSION['username']. "<br>"
         . nl2br($_POST['message']);
```

There's no sanity checks or validation in there but I think that's what you're trying to get it to do.

---- EXAMPLE CODE ----

I've just refactored your code somewhat so I could better see what you're doing (it's just a matter of personal preference) and put comments in to show what I'm getting at with regards to sanity checks and validation.

I've not tested any of this, it's pretty much just an example using your code.

```
<?php
require_once "include/session.php";
require_once "include/dataconnect.php";
require_once "include/functions.php";
require_once "include/mheader.php";

//sanity checks - ensure the form has been posted and that there IS a message
if($_POST && !empty($_POST['message'])) {

  //sanity check - ensure there IS a username
  $sUsername = !empty($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : "";
  if($sUsername) {

    //check the username against the database?
    $resultEmail = mysql_query("SELECT `email` FROM `reusers` WHERE `username` = '{$sUsername}' LIMIT 0, 1")
            or die(mysql_error());

    //no result - could throw an Exception here
    if(mysql_num_rows($resultEmail) == 0) {
      die("No email addresses found for user '{$sUsername}'");
    }

    //email verified against the database
    else {
      $sEmail = mysql_result($resultEmail, 0);

      //create the email
      $headers = "From: noti@r.co.uk\r\n"
            . 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"
            . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"
            . 'Bcc:noti@r.co.uk' . "\r\n";

      $to = $sEmail; //assuming the email address retrieved from the database has already been mxrr checked etc...
      $subject = "copy of your notification"; 

      $body = $sUsername . "<br>"

             //remove slashes as this is going in an email, strip tags and convert newlines to "<br>"
             // since you're using iso-8859-1 there shouldn't be any oddities unless someone completes
             // the form using an Arabic character set (for instance)
            . nl2br(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['message'])));

      //send the email
      if(!mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
        die("sendmail error!");
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Unless it's changed, it replaces new-line characters with `<br>` - which isn't XML well formed; that would require `<br />` - I just prefer my HTML (either XHTML or HTML5) to be XML well formed; I find it easier to remember to terminate everything rather than having to remember which tags can be left open ;)

Comment: It changed from 5.3.0. Passing `true` (the default, actually) as the second parameter will return `<br />`.

Comment: Ah hah; thanks, I've not used the function for a while since I generally don't use `<br>`|`<br />` tags apart from in HTML emails (or when displaying addresses) so I pretty much wrap text "lines" in `<p> ... </p>` instead.

Comment: @CD001 THIS WORKED $body = $_SESSION['username']. "<br>"
         . nl2br($_POST['message']);  IS THERE ANY PROBLEM WITH IT

Comment: The only problem is that it's not doing any sanity/security checks; you're accepting input from a form so it should really be sanitised first... `strip_tags()` at the very least. But there should probably also be provisos like just checking that the variables have been instantiated (`isset()` or `!empty()`) ... standard stuff when accepting form input.

Comment: @CD001 LOOK AT THE FULL CODE I HAVE UPLOADED IS THE SECURITY ENOUGH

Comment: @lostty84 : I've just added an example in commenting the code to show the kind of sanity checks I'd consider doing. I had to refactor it though as I was working through the checks - I hope it still makes sense :)

Comment: @CD001 i was working with the refactoring , it is alright , t is sending to the bcc address except the email from the database, then i changed the querry to $resultEmail = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM reusers WHERE username = '$sUsername' LIMIT 0, 1")
            or die(mysql_error()); but still no result, but amazing that the other email sent has the username displayed at the top of the email

Comment: @CD001 when i echoed it echo "$sEmail"; it came back with the first letter of the user email

Comment: @lostty84 : my bad; misconstrued what `mysql_result()` actually does - I think I've fixed it now. Weirdly I've never used it before since I always use a database abstraction library (so my code always looks something like `$db->read($sQuery)` which always returns an array even if there's only 1 result).

Answer (score 0):

try this;

`$body = "Username" . "<br>";`

`$body .= "test1 message for test 1 message for test 1message for test 1message for test 1message for test 1message for test 1message for test 1message for test 1message for test 1message for test 1message for test 1message for test 1message for test 1message for test 1message for test 1message for test 1
test2 message for test 2
test3 message for test 3";`

`$body = nl2br($body);`

**and here what i got** [image]